# How to set bridge adapter in bonding interface?

Tags: centos, centos7

I have my bonding interface with name, `agee` I have to copy its setting to `br-ex` adapter, but when I do I lose connectivity and I can't do anything how I do this? I do this setting on the `br - ex` adapter.

```
DEVICE=br-ex
DEVICETYPE=ovs
TYPE=OVSBridge
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=172.17.85.101 
NETMASK=255.255.255.0  
GATEWAY=172.17.85.254  
DNS1=8.8.8.8     
ONBOOT=yes
```